# How did Guilford survive the FLEIJA?

Tags: code-geass

In the Second Battle for Tokyo, Suzaku fires a FLEIJA which destroys a vast amount of the settlement. Guilford pushes the Shinkiro out of the blast radius and is absorbed. How could he  have survived? My only thought is last minute ejection, but I would like a solid answer or other theories that seem plausible.

Answer (score 4):

I recently re-watched the episode in question and I noticed that it does not show Guilford actually being consumed by the FLEIJA. Upon close examination the blast actually stops just short of were he would have been floating. This could have easily allowed for a quick ejection or a use of the thrusters, attached to the back of the float system, which he could have used to escape. After that, if Guilfordhad used the thrusters, he would have been caught in the minor vacuum which would most likely have destroyed his Vincent and it would have prevented him from returning.

Comment: And he is shown SEVERELY injuried MONTHS after that.

Answer (score 1):

If he had been hit by the FLEIJA Guilford and his mech would have been annihilated. Since we later see him again, we can only conclude that he must have been close to the explosion but didn't get hit.
Most likely the communication system of his knightmare frame malfunctioned after being so close to the explosion which is why the video feed to Lelouch's mech suddenly stopped.
Presumably his mech then crashed and caused the injuries which we later see.